# jboss wildfly 17.0.1 - What is the correct location of silent authentication challenge file?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Hi there, after reading many articles on internet, I know that jboss wildfly writes a challenge file in tmp directory for silent authentication (JBOSS-LOCAL-USER mechanism).

Per my understanding, the challenge file should be located at, e.g. $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/auth/local2639861357474361285.challenge. If the management cli client can access the file successfully on the same machine, silent authentication succeeds.

Let's say:

App server hostname: appserver

jboss wildfly version: 17.0.1

wildfly is running as a service account - wildfly:wildfly

My account for works: mike

If I ssh to appserver using mike, and then run $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c, I think that I should fail the silent authentication, but it succeeds eventually. And then I try:

1. tcpdump to listen 9990 to see if any valuable information, and found:

> 0x0000:  4500 0060 abf6 4000 4006 9721 0a3f 7181  E..`..@.@..!.?q.
>
> 0x0010:  0a3f 7181 276a 932e 7a86 87cf 5604 7121  .?q.'j..z...V.q!
>
> 0x0020:  8018 0058 f7d2 0000 0101 080a 0fcc 2e80  ...X............
>
> 0x0030:  0fcc 2e6a 0000 0028 032f 746d 702f 6c6f  ...j...(**./tmp/lo**
>
> 0x0040:  6361 6c35 3336 3339 3030 3330 3638 3933  **cal5363900306893**
>
> 0x0050:  3137 3238 3532 2e63 6861 6c6c 656e 6765  **172852.challenge**

2. auditctl various path to see if any valuable information, and found that the challenge file is created at **/tmp/**

Is there any system properties to set the location of challenge file? Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that Wildfly is using the `java.io.tmpdir` system property.  One way to override this is to run `standalone.sh` with a command line.  If I run `$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp` for example I can see in the startup logs:

```
...
    java.io.tmpdir = /var/tmp
...
```

Without it I get:

```
...
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
...
```

Comment: Hi @stdunbar, thanks for your reply. Upon specifing java.io.tmpdir, the challenge file is saved to the specific location. I downloaded 14.0.1, 17.0.0 and 17.0.1 and run standalone.sh with **default settings" (just specify bind address as 127.0.0.1), I found that in all cases, the challenge file is saved to $jboss_home/standalone/tmp/auth. My jboss wildfly 17.0.1 is configured for using elytron in several areas. I don't know if such settings cause the issue...anyway, I will keep trying. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that upon I configure the http-interface according to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Elytron+Subsystem#ElytronSubsystem-usedefaultelytronmgmtauth, my http-interface settings become:

```
 <management-interfaces>
        <http-interface http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication" ssl-context="httpsSSC">
            <http-upgrade enabled="true" sasl-authentication-factory="management-sasl-authentication"/>
            <socket-binding http="management-http" https="management-https"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
```

The challenge file will be created at /tmp/localxxxxxxxx.challenge.

Finally, I decide to stick with the default settings instead of using elytron for management authentication.